# How do I translate custom fields in WP?

Tags: wordpress, translate

I am using this extension: https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/qtranslate-x.

I want to translate some custom fields. By default they are not working. Please check the image.[image: desp]

As you can see I changed from db the value of the label with:

```
[:ro] and [:ru]
```

But it is not working if I click on any tab(Ro or RU). It works only for the `Title`. Is there a way to translate those custom fields?

Comment: How to work with custom fields is [documented in the Plugin documentation](https://qtranslatexteam.wordpress.com/integration/).

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-translate-a-custom-field-with-qtranslate-1